# Change from click detect to proximity prompt

Tags: lua, roblox

I tried a variety of things to try and swap this from click to proximity. Not too sure. I figured since it's proximity, you'd make a separate script, but even doing that, was still giving me troubles. Instead of clicking the button (it's a FPS game), I want it to do the same exact thing, but using proximity prompt so players can "click" to button by hitting the "e" key. Want to learn! Thanks in advance.

```
local tweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local event = Instance.new("BindableEvent")

local Door = script.Parent
local DoorMain = script.Parent.Parent.Frame
local TweenedCompleted = "N/A"
local DoorStatus = "Closed"
local Debounce = false

local function tweenModel(model, cframe, time)
    local cframeValue = Instance.new("CFrameValue")
    cframeValue.Value = model:GetPrimaryPartCFrame()

    cframeValue:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Value"):connect(function()
        model:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(cframeValue.Value)
    end)

    local info = TweenInfo.new(time, Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, Enum.EasingDirection.InOut)
    local tween = tweenService:Create(cframeValue, info, {Value = cframe})
    tween:Play()

    tween.Completed:connect(function()
        cframeValue:Destroy()
    end)
end

local cframes = {
    door1orig = Door.Door1.Center.CFrame,
    door1TGP = Door.Door1.ToGoPos.CFrame,
    door2orig = Door.Door2.Center.CFrame,
    door2TGP = Door.Door2.ToGoPos.CFrame
}

local function Open()
    tweenModel(script.Parent.Door1, cframes.door1TGP, 5)
    wait(2.35)
    tweenModel(script.Parent.Door2, cframes.door2TGP, 2.65)
    wait(3)
end

local function Close()
    tweenModel(script.Parent.Door1, cframes.door1orig, 5)
    tweenModel(script.Parent.Door2, cframes.door2orig, 3)
    wait(5)
end
--//Toggle event//--
script.Parent.Button1.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    if DoorStatus == "Closed" and Debounce == false then
        Debounce = true
        Door.Button1.Click:Play()
        DoorMain.Sound:Play()
        Open()
        wait(1)
        DoorStatus = "Opened"
        Debounce = false
    elseif DoorStatus == "Opened" and Debounce == false then
        Debounce = true
        Door.Button1.Click:Play()
        DoorMain.Sound:Play()
        Close()
        wait(1)
        DoorStatus = "Closed"
        Debounce = false
    end
end)

script.Parent.Button2.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    if DoorStatus == "Closed" and Debounce == false then
        Debounce = true
        Door.Button2.Click:Play()
        DoorMain.Sound:Play()
        Open()
        wait(1)
        DoorStatus = "Opened"
        Debounce = false
    elseif DoorStatus == "Opened" and Debounce == false then
        Debounce = true
        Door.Button2.Click:Play()
        DoorMain.Sound:Play()
        Close()
        wait(1)
        DoorStatus = "Closed"
        Debounce = false
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a proximity prompt in the buttons.
Connect the .Triggered event of the proximity prompt to a function. It should look something like this

```
script.Parent.Button2.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function()

end)
```

After you are done changing the events you can customize the proximity prompt.

Comment: Man... I TRIED THAT! Hahaha! And it wouldn't work for me. That's too funny. Gotta love peer reviews! And I just tested it and it worked as intended... Haha! I honestly don't know what I did wrong for it to never work for me last night.

Cheers, mate!!